# ListElement fields as properties?

Tags: qt, qml

Here is my code :

```
import QtQuick 1.0

ListModel {
    property real firstValue: 2
    property real secondValue: 3
    property real thirdValue: 1
    id: leftGrid
    ListElement {
        icon: "Images/1.png"
        value: leftGrid.firstValue
    }
    ListElement {
        icon: "2.png"
        value: -1
    }
    ListElement {
        icon: "3.png"
        value: leftGrid.secondValue
    }
    ListElement {
        icon: "4.png"
        value: leftGrid.thirdValue
    }
}
```

This gives me the error:

```
ListElement: cannot use script for property value
```

What should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I had this problem as well. Consider adopting one of the solutions reported in here: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-16289 according to your version of Qt as explained.

I personally prefer to implement the model in C++. Read this: http://cdumez.blogspot.com/2010/11/how-to-use-c-list-model-in-qml.html.

Comment: The new link is: https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-20631 but the bug report was closed and replaced with https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/QTBUG-16289

Answer (score 25):

The `ListElement` fields are not QML properties in the traditional sense, but rather the roles in its parent `ListModel`. So property binding does not work in this case. That is why you get QML error: "ListElement: cannot use script for property value", which is a bit confusing.

Although there has been a request submitted to the Qt Team to have this fixed, so far no resolution has been implemented.

In the meantime, if you do not want to implement your own C++ class to handle the list model, as suggested by @Luca Carlon, there is a QML workaround/solution I have tried which works. The main points are:

- Do not use `ListModel` when its fields need to reference other properties.
- Instead, use `ListModel.append()` for the model initialization, and use `ListModel.setProperty()` for the model updating. Inside the argument list of these 2 method calls, the roles can be assigned to the other properties, which is equivalent to property binding.

Applying this QML workaround/solution to your original example code will result in the following revised example code:

```
import QtQuick 2.0

Rectangle {
    width: 400
    height: 200

    ListModel {
        property real firstValue: 2
        property real secondValue: 3
        property real thirdValue: 1
        id: leftGrid

    // The commented-out code belowwon't work:
    // ListElement:Cannot use script for property value.
    //        ListElement {
    //            icon: "Images/1.png"
    //            value: leftGrid.firstValue
    //        }
    //        ListElement {
    //            icon: "2.png"
    //            value: -1
    //        }
    //        ListElement {
    //            icon: "3.png"
    //            value: leftGrid.secondValue
    //        }
    //        ListElement {
    //            icon: "4.png"
    //            value: leftGrid.thirdValue
    //        }
    // QML workaround/solution to the above code:

        // 1. Initialize the list model:
        property bool completed: false
        Component.onCompleted: {
            append({"icon": "Images/1.png", value: leftGrid.firstValue});
            append({"icon": "2.png", value: -1});
            append({"icon": "3.png", value: leftGrid.secondValue});
            append({"icon": "4.png", value: leftGrid.thirdValue});
            completed = true;
        }

        // 2. Update the list model:
        onFirstValueChanged: {
            if(completed) setProperty(0, "value", leftGrid.firstValue);
        }
        onSecondValueChanged: {
            if(completed) setProperty(2, "value", leftGrid.secondValue);
        }
        onThirdValueChanged: {
            if(completed) setProperty(3, "value", leftGrid.thirdValue);
        }
    }
}
```

If you run the above revised example code, using Qt 5.5.0 for example, you will no longer get the QML error. Sure, I do not like this QML workaround/solution either.

Answer (score 3):

My solution to this is not using `ListElement` as model item:

```
property real firstValue: 2
...

ComboBox
{
    model: [
        { text: firstValue, value: firstValue },
        { text: secondValue, value: secondValue },
        { text: thirdValue, value: thirdValue }
    ]

    ...
}
```

Comment: js model in Repeater behav are strage : 1) Repeater remove all 2) Repeater iterata over js array.
all items are iterate over and over.... 

and if you `myModel.push({ .. some item object}.. )`  - Repetar can not detect it ! need replace js array to other instance. 

it "not optimal" and even harder

Answer (score 1):

This error can also occur if you try to reference an enum from C++ that is not registered with Q_ENUM.

Answer (score 1):

This also could be another workaround since ["Beginning with Qt 5.11 ListElement also allows assigning a function declaration to a role. This allows the definition of ListElements with callable actions."](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qml-qtqml-models-listelement.html)

```
import QtQuick

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")
    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent

        ListModel {
            id: fruitModel
            property real appleValue: 2.45
            property real orangeValue: 3.25
            property real bananaValue: 1.95
            ListElement {
                name: "Apple"
                // cost: 2.45
                // cost: fluidModel.appleValue // Error: ListElement: cannot use script for property value
                cost: function(newCost = 2.45){// value 2.45 could be stored in a persistent setting
                    return (fruitModel.appleValue = newCost);
                }
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "Orange"
                // cost: 3.25
                // cost: fluidModel.orangeValue // Error: ListElement: cannot use script for property value
                cost: function(newCost = 3.25){
                    return (fruitModel.orangeValue = newCost);
                }
            }
            ListElement {
                name: "Banana"
                // cost: 1.95
                // cost: fluidModel.bananaValue // Error: ListElement: cannot use script for property value
                cost: function(newCost = 1.95){
                    return (fruitModel.bananaValue = newCost);
                }
            }
        }

        Component {
            id: fruitDelegate
            Row {
                spacing: 10
                Text { text: name }
                // Text { text: '$' + cost } // if value
                Text { text: '$' + cost() } // if function
            }
        }

        ListView {
            anchors.fill: parent
            model: fruitModel
            delegate: fruitDelegate
        }
    }
}
```