# ListElement: cannot use script for property value error

Tags: qt, qml

I have separated module with constant colors:

AppTheme.qml
(cutted file for example)

```
pragma Singleton

import QtQuick 2.12

QtObject {
    readonly property color textColor: "#de000000"   // 87%
    readonly property color textColor54: "#8a000000"
    readonly property color textColor38: "#61000000"
    readonly property color textColor12: "#1e000000"
}
```

In other module I want to create ListModel. In example:

```
ListModel {
    ListElement { param: 0.0; color: AppTheme.textColor }
    ListElement { param: 1.0; color: AppTheme.textColor12 }
}
```

And then I run get this error:

> cannot use script for property value

But I don't understand what happens. Because ListElement created with constant color values. I don't use any functions... Please help me to solve this.

Thank you.

P.S. Now I use hack with Completed event.

```
ListModel {
            Component.onCompleted: {
                [
                [ 0.0,  AppTheme.textColor ],
                [ 1.0,  AppTheme.textColor12 ]
                ].forEach(function(element) {
                    append({
                               param: element[0],
                               color: element[1]
                           });
                });
            }
```

But I think that is not so good and usable...

Comment: Look at this post: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7659442/listelement-fields-as-properties

Comment: I see this post. But I have constants in my module. I don't need property binding e.t.c.

Comment: They are properties anyway although they are constants. You are right, it would be much better to be able to assign properties to ListElement roles. I think this is an issue with Qt and could be fixed in a future release.